# using sqlite with images

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I'm using sqlite for loading details like, title, actor, director,....
I'm also trying to load a movie poster. I can't figure out how to reference images from sqlite.

I'm using javascript and using a BLOB isn't an option.

here is a bit of the code I'm using to pull content.

```
 db.transaction(
  function(tx) {
   var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mydb');
   r=""
switch (b){
   case "title":
       r += rs.rows.item(a).title
       break;
   case "actor":
       r += rs.rows.item(a).actor
       break;
   case "director":
       r += rs.rows.item(a).director
       break;
   case "genre":
       r += rs.rows.item(a).genre
       break;
   case "rating":
       r += rs.rows.item(a).rating
       break;
   case "detail":
       r += rs.rows.item(a).detail
       break;
   case "image":
       r += rs.rows.item(a).image
       break;}
})
```

Can I just store the image file path?

Comment: Is this in a web context ? If yes, why would you have database on client side ?
I assume you could store paths to your images as you just said.

Comment: I'm using qtquick so it's non client side

Comment: Mmmmh looks interesting.

Comment: you can store any binary stuff/non binary stuff in base64 encoded strings , then just append the result to the src of an image tag, if you are in the browser. look for html5 data urls

Comment: I was going to answer base64 until I saw @mpm's comment. If you don't know, base64 maps converts arbitrary bytes to human readable characters, so that binary data can be packaged in anything that handles strings. It's how email (a text protocol) handles binary files.

Comment: If this is going to be accessed over the internet, I'd recommend for large images to reference them using a URL, i.e. `www.yourdomain.com/image?id=134` and make sure that your `image` script sends an appropriate `Cache-control` header.  You don't want your users to have to re-download a megabyte of images every time they visit a new page if they could have been cached.